# Managed policy reference in an AWS cloud formation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to define a variable for referencing ManagedPolicyARN's based on the environment.
Here's my variable definition:

```
EnvDynamoDbPolicy:
         Type: String
         AllowedPattern: "^arn:aws:iam::.*"
         ConstraintDescription: Must be an IAM policy ARN.
```

Here's where I have defined this variable:

```
  ManagedPolicyArns:
        - ! Ref EnvDynamoDbPolicy
```

When i defined this value

```
EnvDynamoDbPolicy: arn:aws:iam::AccountNumber:policy/staging_test_dynamodb
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ARN Ref EnvDynamoDbPolicy is not valid. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInput
```

Comment: You have a space between ! and Ref

Comment: Thank you .Got past that , but getting the following error - `validation error detected: Value 'Ref EnvParameters' at 'policyArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 20` .                                             How to get around the IAM policy names which are of this format longer than 20 characters - `arn:aws:iam::111111111111:policy/staging_test_dynamodb`

Comment: Can you show how `EnvParameters` is used, as it's not in the code you posted?